# Want help for auto-scroll of content in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll the content of div horizontally and it should be auto-scrolling.. can anyone help me?I tried lots of jquery plugins but still i couldnt do that...any simpler way?help me pls...

Comment: Please clarify your question as this doesn't make a ton of sense in it's current form.

Comment: please show your code for better understanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, set `overflow` to `scroll`, so that any content that overflows out of the `div` will scroll. Make sure `height` is fixed, and be sure to test this with other CSS attributes to get it to work for you.

Comment: Thats not working even I have the same issue, let me know if you any other methods to implement

Comment: @jazza..i tried that by using style tag in html..but i will get a scroll bar... but i want auto scroll of the content...without any scroll bars..any other idea???

Comment: are you asking for a code/plugin that would automatically scroll the div content in a fix width x height?

Comment: Auto scrolling? This requires Javascript. Search Google for "autoscroll content Javascript".

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god, don't use MARQUEE!! There are jQuery plugins you can use..try this one: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/ - Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally i got the answer my own question...I used MARQUEE for my div and it worked.. thanks for all who tried to help me...